# Airflow webserver not starting-UnicodeDecode error

Tags: python, airflow

Im attempting to set up airflow on my mac.I got the basic setup up and running.I was able to create a DAG and schedule it.
All of a sudden I started getting the following error when I start the server:

```
File "/Users/xxx/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/traceback.html", line 27, in top-level template code
{{ nukular }}Node: {{ hostname }}

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Im not sure how to debug this.The server refuses to start.
Thanks!

Comment: Been there. For me it was because some of the characters were treated as non-ascii characters in my template. Try to find out and replace them with ascii chars.

Comment: What's on line 27 in `traceback.html`? And what's in your template that you're using?

Comment: Please include the _complete_ error traceback.  The values of "nukular" and "hostname" would also be useful.

Comment: Adding full traceback as a reply below

Comment: Solved the error:check my comment below